# ng-options directive is not working, unable to find it in library of angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My ng-option directive is not working, It is not being found in the library of AngularJS. I tried almost all the valid sources but still only this directive doesn't work. Even I tried the code present on angularjs.org site.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>View</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var mymodule = angular.module('mymodule' ,[]);
        mymodule.controller('x' , function($scope){
            $scope.point = ['point1' , 'point2' , 'point3' , 'point4'];
            $scope.selectedpoint = $scope.point[1];
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mymodule">
    <div ng-controller="x">
        <select ng-model="selectedpoint" ng-options="item from items in point"></select>
        Select = {{selectedpoint}}
        <hr/>
        <div ng-switch="selectedpoint">
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point1"> First file is selected</div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point2"> Second file is selected</div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point3"> Third file is selected</div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point4"> Fourth file is selected</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I had modified the code, you had used 'from' instead of 'for'
>   [Correct Verion of Code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LkL7LYcwWgcxLOmt7lOg?p=preview)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>View</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var mymodule = angular.module('mymodule' ,[]);
            mymodule.controller('x' , function($scope){
                $scope.point = ['point1' , 'point2' , 'point3' , 'point4'];
                $scope.selectedpoint = $scope.point[1];
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="mymodule">
        <div ng-controller="x">
            <select ng-model="selectedpoint" ng-options="item for item in point"></select>
            Select = {{selectedpoint}}
            <hr/>
            <div ng-switch="selectedpoint">
                <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point1"> First file is selected</div>
                <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point2"> Second file is selected</div>
                <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point3"> Third file is selected</div>
                <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point4"> Fourth file is selected</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @cverb Typo error, just now got the Edit privilege, i had edit my post. please review it and up vote on it

Comment: @cverb Thanks, I am new to stackflow

Comment: For simple typos, instead of providing an answer, it's better to comment and vote to close the question

Comment: @NewDev , We need 50 reputation to comment on the question, When i am answering this question, i had 21 reputation, hence i had answered in the Answer section. If you agree, remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedpoint" ng-options="item as item for item in point"></select>
```

for:

```
<option value="point1">point1</option>
<option value="point2">point2</option>
<option value="point3">point3</option>
```

Or:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedpoint" ng-options="item for item in point"></select>
```

for:

```
<option value="0">point1</option>
<option value="1">point2</option>
<option value="2">point3</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>View</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var mymodule = angular.module('mymodule' ,[]);
        mymodule.controller('x' , function($scope){
            $scope.point = ['point1' , 'point2' , 'point3' , 'point4'];
            $scope.selectedpoint = $scope.point[2];
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mymodule">
    <div ng-controller="x">
        <select ng-model="selectedpoint" ng-options="item for item in point">1</select>
        Select = {{selectedpoint}}
        <hr/>
        <div ng-switch="selectedpoint">
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point1"> First file is selected</div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point2"> Second file is selected</div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point3"> Third file is selected</div>
            <div style="border: 1px solid;" ng-switch-when="point4"> Fourth file is selected</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Have Fun..!!

Answer (score 0):

You did the mistake in ng-options, I correct the your code

```
<select ng-model="selectedpoint" ng-options="item as item for items in point"></select>
```

point is scope values from controller. that assigned to items then we spilt value and name before for items.